# Laravel View::make after filter?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to someone have an after filter for the View::make? What im trying todo is to run the content from View::make that is returned, through an HTML minifier.

I already have App::after that minifies the final html doc. But see, im putting the View::make response into a json object (for ajax requests) and i need the response to be minified.

Answer (score 1):

After filters generally work after the response has been sent to the user.

So to minify the HTML that the user will see need to be processed before it is sent.

But before filters will not work here either. As they are called before the controller method is processed.

So you will have to your process to be used within your controller, a possible solution could be to use a helper function with your minify code, or as a function within your `BaseController`, which is accessible to all your controllers which called the helper function.

You can do the following within your controller;

```
$view = View::make('view.path', $data)->render()
```

This will render and process the view into the HTML the user will see.

You can then pass this to the function you have to minify the HTML and insert it into the JSON response.

Comment: But, see the problem here is that I'm not calling these View helpers inside a controller. They are being called within a library. I do have a helper function that I use to minify the output, but I dont want to make sure I remember to pass the View through the minfier each time, rather make it a global hook of some sort. Surly there is a way!

Comment: That's why I say make a function with your basecontroller allowing all controllers to access this method or hook as you call it.

Comment: Ill reiterate, "I'm not calling these View helpers inside a controller." They are coming from random locations, I suppose I could make a static function and call it via the namespace route, but surly there is a way to do this without having to pass it through a function explicitly, it completely violates the DRY principle...

Comment: You could use an event, and fire the event each time a view is to be made, passing the data, i.e. the view html to be minified. Only thing is there is no way to explictly call this unless you change/extend the inerds of the framework to your own needs.